# Find the nearest matching domain for the url Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, url, string-matching, brute-force

Example
If the Domains are:

1.google.com

2.go.google.com

3.pro.go.google.com

And the input urls are:

***hello.go.google.com*** //will return domain 2 (go.google.com as it is the nearest)

***abc.hello.go.google.com*** // will return domain 2 (go.google.com as it is the nearest)

***qwert.pro.go.google.com*** // will return domain 3 (pro.go.google.com as it is the nearest)

***pro1.go.google.com*** // will return domain 2 (go.google.com as it is the nearest)

***xyz.google.com*** // will return domain 1(google.com as it is the nearest)

I have created a brute force algo and it is working but it fails in one case that is:

Input url : ***xgo.google.com*** //returns domain 2 that is go.google.com but should return 1 that is google.com

Below is the source code I tried:

```
const domainArr = ["google.com", "go.google.com", "pro.go.google.com"];
const pureHostName = "xgo.google.com";

let maxLength = 0;
let selectedDomain = "";
for (let i = 0; i < domainArr.length; i++) {
    const domain = domainArr[i];
    if (pureHostName.includes(domain)) {
        if (i === 0) {
            maxLength = domain.length;
            selectedDomain = domain;
        }
        if (domain.length > maxLength) {
            maxLength = domain.length;
            selectedDomain = domain;
        }
    }
}

console.log("selectedDomain--->", selectedDomain); //returning go.google.com instead of google.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first is to sort the domains based on length of the subdomains for each domain and put longer count of subdomains first and shorter ones later.

Then, check with each domain one by one. If the current testcase at hand matches exactly or has a subdomain when we prepend a period character to our current domain in iteration, we found a match. Otherwise, continue the same test with other available domains.

```js
const domainArr = ["google.com", "go.google.com", "pro.go.google.com"];
const testCases = [
  "hello.go.google.com",
  "abc.hello.go.google.com",
  "qwert.pro.go.google.com",
  "pro1.go.google.com",
  "xyz.google.com"
];

domainArr.sort((a, b) => b.split('.').length - a.split('.').length);

for (let i = 0; i < testCases.length; ++i) {
  let match = 'No match found!';
  for (let j = 0; j < domainArr.length; ++j) {
    if (testCases[i] == domainArr[j] || testCases[i].includes("." + domainArr[j])) {
      match = domainArr[j];
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(testCases[i] + " => " + match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you need to match the first domain in `domainArr`. So, you need to update your code just to stop when finding the matching domain and remove the extra `if` statements:

```
const domainArr = ["google.com", "go.google.com", "pro.go.google.com"];
const pureHostName = "xgo.google.com";

let maxLength = 0;
let selectedDomain = "";
for (let i = 0; i < domainArr.length; i++) {
    const domain = domainArr[i];
    if (pureHostName.includes(domain)) {
        maxLength = domain.length;
        selectedDomain = domain;

        //Add this
        break;
    }
}

console.log("selectedDomain--->", selectedDomain);
```

Let me know if that solves your issue

Comment: what if the sequence of domainArr changes ? This is not the solution.

Comment: My solution assume that `domainArr` sorted based on length. Basically, you can sort the array content based on length

Answer (score 0):

This is similar in technique to the answer from nice_dev, but it presents a different API.  You supply your list of domains to a function, it sorts (a shallow clone of) them and returns a function which takes a domain and find the parent domain (or an empty string if none of them match.)

```js
const parentDomain = (domains) => {
  const sorted = [...domains] .sort (
    (a, b) => b .split ('.') .length - a .split ('.') .length
  ) 
  return (domain) => sorted .find ((d) => domain .endsWith ('.' + d)) || ''
}

const googleDomain = parentDomain (["google.com", "go.google.com", "pro.go.google.com"]) 


const testCases = ['hello.go.google.com', 'abc.hello.go.google.com', 'qwert.pro.go.google.com', 
                   'pro1.go.google.com', 'xyz.google.com', 'xgo.google.com']
testCases .forEach (url => console .log (`"${url}" ==> "${googleDomain (url)}"`))
```